# rspec: how can I continue test after first failure

Tags: ruby, loops, testing, rspec

I am using rspec to system test a device. The device is modular so that any number of sub-devices may be connected to a test rig. There are many places where I want to write tests that will loop over the connected of sub-devices and run the same test on each device.

Basically, this is what I am trying to do:

```
before(:all)   
  @tool = discover_sub_devices()
  @tool.sub_devices.should == exp_sub_device_list
end

describe "some sub device tests" do
  @tool.sub_devices.each do |dev|   
    it "should succeed at doing things" do
      dev.do_thing.should == success   
    end 
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I get errors saying @tool is nill and does not contain a class `sub_devices` before the tests even run. So the tests are being parsed before the `before(:all)` block runs.

One way I can make it work is by putting the loop inside of the `it` block. Like this:

```
it "should succeed at doing things" do
  @tool.sub_devices.each do |dev| 
    dev.do_thing.should == success   
  end
end
```

The problem with doing it this way is that I really want to test all the sub-devices even if the first one fails. I want to see a report of exactly how many sub devices had failures. This code will break out as soon as one fails and not test the rest.

I realize this is probably not a normal use case for rspec but it would be very convenient for our testing situation if I could make this work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some techniques for writing this.

It is best to avoid using `before :all`. It is also best to avoid making objects outside of examples.

```
describe "some sub device tests" do

  let(:tool) { discover_sub_devices }

  it "matches the sub device list" do
    tool.sub_devices.should be == expected_sub_devices_list
  end

  it "succeeds with all sub-devices" do
    failures = tool.sub_devices.reject{|d| d.do_thing == success}

    # option 1
    failures.should be_empty # will show just a yes/no result

    # option 2
    failures.size.should be == 0 # will show the number of failures

    # option 3
    failures.should be == [] # will display all sub-devices which fail
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that the body of a `describe` block gets executed immediately, while the bodies of the `let`, `before` and `it` blocks get executed at a later time.

Assuming you don't need to rediscover the devices each time, you can refactor your code as follows, eliminating the `before` call:

```
describe "some sub device tests" do
  tool = discover_sub_devices()
  it "should discover sub devices correctly" do
     tool.sub_devices.should == exp_sub_device_list
  end
  tool.sub_devices.each do |dev|   
    it "should succeed at doing things" do
      dev.do_thing.should == success   
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Great suggestion but I can't seem to get this to work. @tool always seems to be nil.

Comment: I think the problem is that the @tool inside the it block and the one outside the it block do not have the same scope :(

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot that instance variables don't work with this technique.  See updated answer.