# How to fail fast only specific rspec test script?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec3

I have a test suite of rspec tests which are divided into different files.
Every file represents one test scenario with some number of test steps.
Now, on some particular tests, it can happen that specific step fails but it is too time consuming and not needed to run rest of the steps in that scenario.

I know there is an option --fail-fast in rspec but if I'm running tests like: rspec spec/* that will mean that when first step fails in any script, it will abort complete execution.
I'm just looking for mechanism to abort execution of that specific test scenario (test script) when failure happens but to continue execution of other test scenarios.

Thanks for the help,
Bakir

Comment: `RSpec` is designed to run in kinda automated environment, that’s why the functionality you requested is not available out of the box. Though there are two possibilities to avoid a limitation. I personally prefer using https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec, but you might find [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828790/rspec-how-can-i-continue-test-after-first-failure) more applicable to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RSpec-instafail gem](https://github.com/grosser/rspec-instafail).

According to its documentation, it:

```
Show failing specs instantly. Show passing spec as green dots as usual.
```